# Writing values as an arbitrary amount of bits into a byte buffer in C++

Tags: c++, networking, bit-manipulation

Hey, I need to pack bit values into a byte buffer in C++.  My Buffer class has a char array and a position, similar to Java's ByteBuffer.  I need a good way to pack bits into this buffer, like so:

```
void put_bits(int amount, uint32_t value);
```

It needs to support up to 32 bits.  I've seen a solution implemented in Java (that requires start/end access methods before bits can be packed) but I'm not sure how to do this in C++ because the endianness and other low level factors aren't hidden like they are in Java.

I have an inline function declared as `endianness()` which returns 0 (defined as `BIG_ENDIAN`) or 1 (defined as `LITTLE_ENDIAN`) that can be used, but I'm just not sure how to properly pack bits into a byte buffer.

This is the Java version of what I need to implement:

```
public void writeBits(int numBits, int value) {
    int bytePos = bitPosition >> 3;
    int bitOffset = 8 - (bitPosition & 7);
    bitPosition += numBits;

    for(; numBits > bitOffset; bitOffset = 8) {
        buffer[bytePos] &= ~ bitMaskOut[bitOffset];
        buffer[bytePos++] |= (value >> (numBits-bitOffset)) & bitMaskOut[bitOffset];

        numBits -= bitOffset;
    }
    if(numBits == bitOffset) {
        buffer[bytePos] &= ~ bitMaskOut[bitOffset];
        buffer[bytePos] |= value & bitMaskOut[bitOffset];
    }
    else {
        buffer[bytePos] &= ~ (bitMaskOut[numBits]<<(bitOffset - numBits));
        buffer[bytePos] |= (value&bitMaskOut[numBits]) << (bitOffset - numBits);
    }
}
```

Which requires these two methods as well:

```
public void initBitAccess() {
    bitPosition = currentOffset * 8;
}

public void finishBitAccess() {
    currentOffset = (bitPosition + 7) / 8;
}
```

How should I go about solving this?  Thanks.

EDIT: I also still need to be able to write normal bytes before and after writing bits.

Comment: Well, the Java version is pretty much valid C++, so it shouldn't be hard to translate it.  Is this homework?

Comment: Refer to the std::bitset library: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/

Answer (score 3):

Just remove all the `public` keywords, and I would say that you have your `C++` implementation right there.

Comment: Are you sure?  x86 is by default little endian and Java operates in by default big endian.  Wouldn't that make a difference for something like this?

Comment: It really doesn't matter in this case, as outlined in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you use the byte buffer only as such, you can translate the Java code one-to-one. It only gets dangerous if you interpret a byte pointer as another type and try to store a complete int in the byte buffer.

You don't even need the `endianness` function in this case, since you store a byte in a byte buffer, and there is nothing to convert or adjust size or whatever.